# How to calculate year to date from columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

| Category | Shop | January Sales | February Sales | March Sales | April Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Lion | 1000 | 3405 | 2865 | 3995 |
| A1 | Tiger | 6885 | 8321 | 4866 | 5784 |
| A2 | Lion | 4854 | 3958 | 3110 | 4100 |
| A2 | Jaguar | 2884 | 3611 | 5883 | 9211 |
| A1 | Crocodile | 4005 | 3405 | 8000 | 8533 |
| A3 | Horse | 1002 | 805 | 1000 | 585 |

I need to calculate the ytd column accoring to category and shop

Thanks in advance!

Comment: kindly post your expected output. what did you try?

Comment: I tried to this `df['ytd'] = df['January Sales'] + df['February Sales']...` But it does not return correct output. It should look like Lion shop category A1 ytd = XXX

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to see Category and Shop with YTD output.

You just need to select the right columns.

```py
df['ytd'] = df['January Sales'] + df['February Sales'] + df['March Sales']  + df['April Sales']
```